# Passing of information by tabs

Tags: java

Currently i have this inside my main class.

So i'm trying to create an object in order to pass information around, between the two tabs. for example after making a new order, i can go to the next tab to check the orders.

```
Book b = new Book();
```

So i tried to pass the object by.

I just started learning java a few weeks ago so please keep it simple. thanks alot.

And i'm trying doing it without a submit button, so when i click on the next tab, it will call the listener and store the infomation into the object. is it possible?

Comment: tp.addTab("New Order", Order.main(b)); makes no sense. What do you mean, "in order to pass information around"?  PLease read the FAQ on how to ask questions - http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: what is "public static void main (book b)" for...your main method should be public static void main(String[] args)...void just means nothing is returned...code for the class of "tp" needs to be included

Answer (score 1):

the main method, doesn't return any value, so you can't pass it's return value to another method like that.

I think you want something like

```
public class Order extends JPanel
{
    public Book b;
    public Order()
    {
        b = new Book();
    }
    ...
}
```

and then you can pass it as

```
AMethodThatUsesBook(myOrder.b)
```

---

or you might be trying to instantiate the object

```
Order myOrder = new Order();
```

and then you can pass that as a value

```
tp.addTab("New Order", myOrder);
```

Comment: Another thing, `public static void main (book b)` is wrong. `main` method should accept an array of strings.

Comment: how do i pass the objects through tabs?